# Generate referral short links using Branch SDK android

Tags: android, deep-linking, branch.io

I want to implement a referral system in my app using branch SDK. I want to generate a short link with my static custom endpoint (https://app.link/ABC123) for each user which can be shared by other users. I can do this by setting alias on `LinkProperties`. But using alias with `BUO.showShareSheet` gives an error.

Can I use an alias with `BUO.showShareSheet`?

Should the Canonical identifier unique for each URL?

Is it possible to set multiple channels using `LinkProperties`?

Does the same URL generate every time if all arguments are same for `BUO` & `LinkProperties`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. Can I use an alias with BUO.showShareSheet?**

You can definitely use alias with the showShareSheet method. Here is the code I used to generate and share an alias link

```
final BranchUniversalObject branchUniversalObject = new BranchUniversalObject()
                        .setCanonicalIdentifier("/1234")
                        .setTitle("Test for alias")
                        .setContentDescription("Your friend has invited you to check out my app!")                      .setContentImageUrl("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5a/Branch_Metrics_logo_color.png/1200px-Branch_Metrics_logo_color.png")
                        .addContentMetadata("var1", "abc")
                        .addContentMetadata("var2", "def");

                LinkProperties linkProperties = new LinkProperties()
                        .setChannel("Facebook")
                        .setFeature("Sharing")
                        .setAlias("aliastest");

                ShareSheetStyle ss = new ShareSheetStyle(MainActivity.this, "Check this out!", "This stuff is awesome: ")
                .setCopyUrlStyle(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, android.R.drawable.ic_menu_send), "Copy", "Added to clipboard")
                .setMoreOptionStyle(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, android.R.drawable.ic_menu_search), "Show more")
                .addPreferredSharingOption(SharingHelper.SHARE_WITH.FACEBOOK)
                .addPreferredSharingOption(SharingHelper.SHARE_WITH.EMAIL)
                .addPreferredSharingOption(SharingHelper.SHARE_WITH.MESSAGE)
                .addPreferredSharingOption(SharingHelper.SHARE_WITH.HANGOUT)
                .setAsFullWidthStyle(true)
                .setSharingTitle("Share With");

        branchUniversalObject.showShareSheet(this, linkProperties,  ss,  new Branch.BranchLinkShareListener() {
            @Override
            public void onShareLinkDialogLaunched() {
            }
            @Override
            public void onShareLinkDialogDismissed() {
            }
            @Override
            public void onLinkShareResponse(String sharedLink, String sharedChannel, BranchError error) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onChannelSelected(String channelName) {
            }
        });
```

> But please note, if you try to generate a link with the same alias and different link parameters, you will receive an alias conflict error and the showShareSheet method would, in turn, give you an error.

**2. Should the Canonical identifier unique for each URL?**

The `canonicalIdentifier` or `canonicalUrl` parameter greatly improves the content analytics data Branch captures. Branch suggests that it should be unique to that piece of content. It, in turn, helps Branch dedupe across many instances of the same thing. Suitable options: a website with pathing, or a database with identifiers for entities.

**3. Is it possible to set multiple channels using LinkProperties?**

You cannot set multiple channels for a single link. The channel tag is used to signify the route that your link reaches users. Hence, there can be only one channel.

**4. Does the same URL generate every time if all arguments are same for BUO & LinkProperties?**

If all the BranchUniversalObject properties and link properties are exactly the same, the `generateShortUrl` and `showShareSheet` will return the same link.

Comment: I have tried it, using alias with sharesheest creates short URL only once. Then it gives an error "Trouble creating a URL. Unable to create a URL with that alias. If you want to reuse the alias, make sure to submit the same properties for all arguments and that the user is the same owner." on selecting other options from dialog. But, creates same every time for the very first selected option.

Comment: @Amrutha Deshmukh

Comment: When creating a link through Share sheet Branch SDK adds an additional link property `channel` with the name of the channel the user has selected e.g. channel=Slack if the user chooses Slack from the shareSheet. Even if you define the channel property for your link, Branch's SDK overrides this value.  Currently, there is no way to create an alias link using the shareSheet to share the link to different platforms. Although, full disclosure, I work for Branch and have informed the issue to the engineering team. They are looking into this feature and will update the SDK accordingly.